# In clash of clans how do you tell if enemy troops can be deployed in certain area?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When buildings are too close together enemy troops can't be deployed between them. How do you tell when they're close enough? I built a wall around my main base (including town centre) but attackers can still deploy troops within the wall.

For ascetic reasons I like having my village spaced out, it's too bad that the game play promotes against it.

[image: screen shot of edit mode]
Here is a screen shot while in edit mode. I have the town hall selected and moved it around a little, but still there are no lines to indicate where attacking troops can't be deployed. I notice there are some white lines outside the walls, but those are different, for example with this current setup I've had enemy troops deployed within the walls.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, troops can be deployed on the second tile away from any structure (including walls but excluding decorations and traps) you have.

Comment: Don't forget decorations and annoyances (ie. trees and stone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell in two ways: During battle, and while editing your base.

---

**Anything shaded in white/red means you/your enemies can't deploy troops there.**

To trigger the boundaries (lines that show where troops can be deployed) while in your village, simply drag a building around. The area will be indicated as a white overlay, which will fade after a few seconds.
Alternatively, in the village editor - The overlay will be shown at all times.

[image]
*The overlay in the village screen.*

To trigger boundaries while during a battle, attempt to place a troop where you cannot place it.
A red boundary line and overlay will appear, showing you where you *can't* place your troops.
*Note: If you attempt to place a troop in an area you can't deploy them during the scouting phase (first 30 seconds of a match), it will not skip you to the battle phase.*

[image]

Comment: hi aytimothy I'm not sure if that's correct. You already have all your buildings placed as close as possible so of course enemy troops don't have any room to deploy within your walls. Take a look at the screen shot I added. Even though there's a white blocky perimeter, enemy troops can be deployed within the walls (for example right beside the town hall).

Comment: http://imgur.com/0Dieo57 | Try moving your buildings closer together or  place a wall to cover up that gap. A rule of thumb of CoC is that enemies can deploy anywhere as long as there's no building 1 tile away. Just note that decorations and annoyances (ie. stone/trees) don't count towards this.

Comment: Oh ok so you're basically saying an enemy can deploy anywhere a decoration or stone is?

Comment: @Celeritas Yes, as long as it's not within your boundaries. For example: The tree in the screenshot I added can be placed on. Your screenshot's stone however is a half-half case.

Comment: And I also forgot: Traps won't increase your border either.

Comment: @Celeritas: the arrow banner next to your town hall is the problem. Decorations like that don't add to the buffer, so if you remove that banner and see a hole in your defenses, that's what it is like even with the banner there.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone said, decorations don't have any protection.

I edited your screenshot and marked all areas where attacking is possible in the screenshot below, you have three unprotected areas.

*Red areas are unprotected*
[image: Red areas are unprotected]

Comment: I'm not sure if the stone is a problem. Once I attacked a village that had a large tree (which is 3x3 just like the stone in this example) inside the walls, but I was unable to deploy any troops at that location.

Comment: Maybe this has been changed in some of the updates since this post. I haven't tried it for some time, so it could have been changed...

Answer (score -2):

The enemy troops can be deployed where the rock is inside your base. Try removing rock and place something else in its place, or put your walls around it so its outside.

Comment: He doesn't need to remove that rock. He can just move a building closer to that place so troops cannot be deployed there

Answer (score -2):

Deco Such as your flag is making it possible to spawn within your walls so move your flag somewhere else and put a builders hut or something that's the on 2x2 thing I can think of,

Comment: More specifically, it's not that the flag itself is *allowing* them to spawn in that location, more that the flag is not *disallowing* them to spawn. As it is just deco, it doesn't "occupy" any space.

Answer (score -4):

They can be deployed behind the white areas :)